# Condition based on today's date in calcualted field

Tags: calculated-column, power-automate, powerapp, date, conditional

I have a calculated column inside a solution Table in Power Automate
[image]

but I need the condition to be check with a value now() - the current date, not a hardcoded value like this. However when I try to entry that I got an error. I have tried entering the date format inside the brackets but it still doesn't work, any many other things like TEXT(NOW(),"mm/dd/yyyy") etc. Any suggestion how to solve this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To get the current date we are using the utcnow() function inside the formateDateTime function with the format ‘M/d/yyyy’.

```
formatDateTime(utcNow(), 'M/d/yyyy')
```